# Filling input with maximum number of available shares

Tags: user-centered-design, experience, ux-writing

**The problem:**

If the user has 5 available shares, and would like to sell those 5 shares, he'd have to input them manually in the below field. Some users have large amount of shares, and i'd like to make it easier to just have it fill out automatically.

Is there a standard way of approaching this problem? Initial thoughts is to have a checkbox that says something along the lines of "Maximum Number of Shares" and the input would automatically fill upon clicking that checkbox.

Curious to hearing your thoughts.

[image: Number of Shares]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow some cues from trading platforms.

In coinbase, they put a subtle 'MAX' label inside the input field.

[image]

Another approach is to quickly give them a ratio to choose from

- 25%, 50%, 75%, max

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could think of either adding a link or a button that sets the number of shares to the maximum value. You could also add a slider.

I would not choose a checkbox, as setting the number of shares to the maximum is more an action then a preference (What would happen if the user checks the box and then changes the number?)

[image: wireframe with link or button]